Get Initializer result from Hilt module
Simple question here: is it possible to get an object initilized through app startup Initializer inside a Hilt module?
Let me provide an example. Assume that I've the following Initializer:
class AnalyticsInitializer: Initializer<Analytics> {
    override fun create(context: Context): Analytics {
        return A
    }
}

and  a Hilt module:
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAnalytics(): Monitor =
    // get the object A returned by AnalyticsInitializer

Any hint? Are there any alternatives?
